# How to Get JSON output from ExchangeOnline command execution using powershell

Tags: json, azure, powershell, foreach

I would like to execute ExchangeOnline command and convert it to JSON by selecting certain properties, all in single command!

For example, the output for my command to get `RecipientPermissions` for each `SharedMailbox` is:

```
// command

Get-EXOMailbox -RecipientTypeDetails "SharedMailbox" -ResultSize unlimited | foreach { Get-EXORecipientPermission -Identity $_.Identity }
```

The sample output for above command is

```
 Identity          : testexosv
 Trustee           : NT AUTHORITY\SELF
 AccessControlType : Allow
 AccessRights      : {SendAs}
 IsInherited       : False
 InheritanceType   : All

 Identity          : SMBP
 Trustee           : 2b33e774737b4da26c2e551c00f
 AccessControlType : Allow
 AccessRights      : {SendAs}
 IsInherited       : False
 InheritanceType   : None
```

Firstly, I would like to convert the above output to JSON. So, if I simply pipe it to `ConvertTo-Json` , the value for `AccessRights` is lost as follows:

```
 [
     {
       "Identity": "SMBP",
       "Trustee": "2b33e774737b4da26c2e551c00f",
       "AccessControlType": "Allow",
       "AccessRights": [
              1
        ],
       "IsInherited": false,
       "InheritanceType": "None"
     },
     {
       "Identity": "testexosv",
       "Trustee": "NT AUTHORITY\\SELF",
       "AccessControlType": "Allow",
       "AccessRights": [
          1
        ],
       "IsInherited": false,
       "InheritanceType": "All"
     }
  ]
```

Secondly, I want to select only specific properties in the result, for example: `Identity, Trustee, AccessRights` , rename them to arbitrary keys and still maintain the Json structure. So the o/p I actually want is:

```
 [
     {
       "ShareMailbox": "SMBP",
       "UPN": "2b33e774737b4da26c2e551c00f",  
       "Roles": [
              "SendAs"
        ]
     },
     {
       "SharedMailbox": "testexosv",
       "UPN": "NT AUTHORITY\\SELF",
       "Roles": [
          "SendAs"
        ]
     }
  ]
```

I have tried following command:

```
 Get-EXOMailbox -RecipientTypeDetails "SharedMailbox" -ResultSize unlimited 
 | foreach { Get-EXORecipientPermission -Identity $_.Identity 
 | foreach {$_.Identity, $_.Trustee, [String]$_.AccessRights } | ConvertTo-Json}
```

But it is just providing the JSON array, and not JSON object. Output for above command is

```
 [
   "SMBP",
   "2b33e774737b4da26c2e551c00f",
   "SendAs"
 ]
 [
   "testexosv",
   "NT AUTHORITY\\SELF",
   "SendAs"
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
Get-EXOMailbox -RecipientTypeDetails "SharedMailbox" -ResultSize unlimited |
 ForEach-Object Identity |
 Get-EXORecipientPermission |
 Select-Object Identity, Trustee, AccessRights |
 ConvertTo-Json -EnumAsStrings
```

Note:

- `Get-EXORecipientPermission` may accept `Get-EXOMailbox` output *directly* as pipeline input (I cannot personally verify that), in which case you can remove the `ForEach-Object Identity` pipeline segment.
- [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) is used to extract only the properties of interest (which are added to `[pscustomobject]` instances with properties of the same name containing static copies of the input objects' property values).
- [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)'s `-EnumAsStrings` switch - available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only - ensures that instances of [`[enum]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Enum)-derived values - which are by default serialized by their *underlying numeric values* - are instead serialized by their *symbolic names*, i.e. as *strings*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just one correction: it is -EnumsAsString (at least this worked for me on Powershell core 7.3.6, OS MacOS)

Comment: @theimpatientcoder, glad to hear it helped; my pleasure. The parameter name is indeed - somewhat unusually - `EnumAsStrings` (plural). The reason that `EnumAsString` (singular) works too is PowerShell's "elastic syntax": any _unambiguous_ parameter-name _prefix_ is recognized too; e.g. `Get-Date | ConvertTo-Json -Enum`